# Simple MySQL query 16 seconds long

Tags: php, mysql, linux

I am running a 8gb ram, quad-core, SSD cloud server.

Most DB queries are fast, but one query updating only one column for one row is taking up to 16 seconds, according to New Relic.

My query is:

```
UPDATE user SET ad=$currentAdSet WHERE ckey='$_COOKIE[ckey]'
```

And I am using the `mysql_query("")` php function to execute the query.

Mu `user` table has around 43000 rows and a simple structure.

Why is this query taking so long? Any ideas?

Comment: Is there an index on the `ckey` column?

Comment: is `ckey` is an index?'

Comment: Nice [SQL injection hole](http://bobby-tables.com). Enjoy having your server pwn3d.

Comment: Even without indexes, the query should not take 15 seconds for just 43k rows. Check if you have any locks on that table while the update is fired. Use EXPLAIN to see the query plan if you believe it is an optimization issue.

Comment: Made `ckey` index and it is much faster now.

Comment: @MarcB Why is this a security hole?

Comment: read the site I linked to. the cartoon on the front explains it all.

Comment: The $currentAdSet variable is determined by the server. Can a cookie be changed manually? Should I sanitize the $_COOKIE variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add an index on `ckey` and check the timing again. I would advise some reading on indexes.

BTW, using directly a cookie value might lead to SQL injection

Answer (score 2):

You can try and see what is making it be so slow by using `EXPLAIN`. Then, based on the bottle necks you see, use indexes.

Comment: Will definitely remember `EXPLAIN` for the future! :)

Answer (score 0):

ensure **ckey** is indexed and, if not needed, **ad** is NOT indexed.

the first will allow faster selection of records, the second faster update

hope this helps